# Unable to copy to system clipboard

Tags: os-clipboard

I'm running vim on a Debian Jessie machine inside of a VirtualBox on my Mac. I'm trying to get `yy` and `p` to work so I can copy and paste across different terminal windows by using the system clipboard. Please note the following:

1) `echo has('clipboard')` returns 1 (I have vim-gtk installed)

2) My .vimrc file is as follows:

```
syntax on
set mouse=a
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

3) I've logged into the ssh session with `ssh -XY me@host>`to allow x11 forwarding

4) The Debian machine is headless.

5) When I'm logged into the machine directly instead of over ssh, I still can't copy to the system clipboard.

When I do `yy` or even `"+yy` and then do `:reg` to look inside the registers, there is no listing for the `"+` register.

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: What does `:reg +` give after `"+yy`? Also, I'd recommend trying `set clipboard=unnamedplus,unnamed`.

Comment: `:reg` doesn't show the `+` register at all. The only way I can get the system clipboard to work is to run the guest with the full GUI and a native terminal app open in the GUI.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What does `:reg +` give? On my machine `:reg +` shows the `*` register, which is why you don't see `+` in the full `:reg` command.

Comment: It doesn't show anything. It doesn't exist.

Comment: You say "terminal" window in the question.  Can you use the clipboard from the terminal itself?  e.g. with `xclip` or `xsel`?  Also, it is very strange that `:echom has("clipboard")` gives `1` and `:reg +` fails (it should be the same code).  What does `vim --version` actually say about the clipboard?

Comment: Vim version reports +clipboard as well as +xterm_clipboard. I tried a solution using `xclip` and `xsel` but I could not get it working. The mapped vim command to xclip seemed to work (though I couldn't tell for sure) but when I went to paste I got some error about it not being able to locate a window, iirc.

Comment: I cannot copy and paste with the mouse but it's not surprising since I'm running a guest machine through an ssh session.

Comment: If you are still looking for it, here is my answer in Stackoverflow [How to copy to clipboard in Vim?
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292909/6361293)